# Getting the ComboBox Value based on the DateTimePicker

Tags: c#

I have a program where if the `DateTimePicker` is set to a specific day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday up to Sunday), the `ComboBox` will only show the times available on that day.

This is my string, however, when I choose Monday then change it to Tuesday then change it again to Wednesday, the previous values of the `ComboBox` just add up instead of just getting the values(times available) for the current chosen day.

[image]

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("8:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("9:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("10:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("1:00 PM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("3:00 PM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("6:00 PM");
    }
    else if (dateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("8:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("9:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("10:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("1:00 PM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("3:00 PM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("6:00 PM");
    }
    else if (dateTimePicker1.Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("8:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("9:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("10:00 AM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("1:00 PM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("3:00 PM");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("6:00 PM");
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("NO TIMES AVAILABLE");
    }
}
```

What do I need to change in order for me to just show the available times for the current chosen day?

Comment: `comboBox1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: If the times are all the same why not just add those times if it's Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday?

Comment: Hi Robert, times are the same for Mon-Fri but different from Sat and Sun :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call `Clear` on the list i.e.:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();

    //...
```